# How to display the alert icon on application icon

Tags: android

I have created application for receieving the message from one perticular number.Its working fine.Now  i want to display the alert icon on inbox application icon after receiving the message.Where should i add the code for that.

```
    if ( extras != null ) {
                // get array data from SMS
                Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get( "pdus" ); // "pdus" is the key

                for ( int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i ) {
                    // get sms message
                    SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);
                    // get content and number
                    String body = sms.getMessageBody();
                    String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
                    // create display message

                    if( address.equals("+91999999999")){


                    messages += "SMS from " + address + " :\n";
                    messages += body + "\n";

               // notify new arriving message
                    Toast.makeText( context, messages, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    listSms.add(new SmsInfo(address, body));
                    this.abortBroadcast();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The icon is hardcoded in the AndroidManifest file. It is designed in this way, so the app icon can be retrieved without running any piece of code (which may result in slower startup for the app)

Some custom home applications support this, but with private APIs.

You can try to use the NotificationManager and add an icon to the status bar. That would be even more visible, which is a more recommended way of doing it. Use the status bar in such cases, for what's its designed for...

In regards to getting a dynamic icon, when the phone receives the message (push notification or whatever) and your app goes to build the notification, you can do a small http request to pull a dynamic icon file before building the notification. This will delay the posting a few seconds, but it doesn't really matter. Then you can get the resulting image and use it in the notification. The specific image can be chosen by sending some data with the (let me guess, push notification) that identifies what photo, such as a url, or an id that you can append onto an already existing url in your notification building part of the app.

Comment: Ya that i did now i want to display the number of unread meassge on main application icon or changing the original icon to new alert icon after receiving the message

Comment: try pulling an icon before building the notification... check the answer

Answer (score 0):

I am sure where you want to display alert badge/icon, but you can check and try to implement: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger